# how to import a property file which is accessed by an import resource

Tags: java, eclipse

i have a an applicationcontext.xml in my test war where im importing an jar's JarapplicationContext.xml. But this JArApplicationContext.xml refers to a property file and im getting that property cannot be found when i run the war in eclipse. I have tried to include that property file in my war but still im getting the property error.

I need to load the property file before the application context is loaded.

Comment: have you put the property file path correctly in the xml where you are loading it ?

Comment: Yes. I have. I am guessing the error is because, the import of all the xmls happens before the load of property files.

Comment: how are you loading property file..show me

Comment: <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:conf/prop.properties" />

Comment: have you put this line before the beans definition in spring config file ? how are you loading all xml files

Comment: im using the import resource to import all the xmls. and i have put the line before all imports.

Comment: can you show your web.xml , how you are loading spring config file using context loader and spring main config file as well ?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
 version="3.0">
 <display-name>tooling</display-name>
 <description>tooling</description>
 
 <context-param>
 <param-name>propertyFileLocation</param-name>
 <param-value>conf/system.properties</param-value>
 </context-param>
 
 <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>
  /META-INF/application-context.xml

Answer (score 0):

Load only spring context file from web.xml and include import resource in this xml

and before import resource you should load property file.

so web.xml should be like below

```
 <context-param> 
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value> /META-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

inside `application-context.xml`

first line after beans tag should be like below

```
<context:property-placeholder location='abc.properties'/>
```